Unbound variable: get-basic-type in GDB Guile session
I execute the following code  in a GDB session and I take the message:
Unbound variable: get-basic-type
What's missing?

Did you include the Usage part?: (use-modules (gdb types))

Of course I did.

As far as I can tell, get-basic-type never existed in the gdb sources (not even in the first submitted version of the patch), only in the documentation. That this was apparently never noticed since its introduction 10 years ago just shows how few people use the guile interface in gdb.

So @ssbssa this is just a bug in the documentation?

Yes, but some saw this question, and submitted a patch to implement get-basic-type.

@ssbssa this is a benign side effect (pun intended) of Stackoverflow posts.
